# manage user properties and adding new mappings

Tags: my-site, synchronisation

Can anyone let me know if i need to do full AD synch after adding a new mapping in manage user properties.  I created a mapping between the mobile user profile property and AD however the mobile numbers don't appear in anybody's mysite.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll want to do a full import after creating the custom property and mapping. I had to do that to get our custom Mail Stop user profile field to show up in My Site profiles after creating it and setting the mapping.

Comment: thanks.  Is there anything i should be worried about when performing a full synch.  Ive never done it before so not sure of the problems / consequences